# If any EditText in a Table is empty

Tags: java, android

In the layout I have a table and two buttons, one button dynamically add another row in the table and the other button is submitted button which stores the values of edittexts inside rows in the table. I want to show a message and cancel submission unless all the edit texts in that table are filled.so it is form validation of a table with the uncertain number of rows with edit texts.
So how to show an error message if any of the edit text inside a table layout is empty.

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: show errormessage if any of the edittext in a Table layout is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code

```
 public boolean isEmpty(ViewGroup viewGroup){

            for(int i=0;i<viewGroup.getChildCount();i++){
                View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
                    boolean isEmpty= isEmpty((ViewGroup) view);

                    if(isEmpty){
                        return true;
                    }
                }else if(view instanceof EditText){
                    EditText editText= (EditText) view;
                    String input = editText.getText().toString();

                    if("".equals(input)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

         return false;
    }
```

so basically u can pass table view instance(which is a viewgroup) or any other viewgroup instance and the method will handle looping through its children to check if any edittext have an empty field